# Is it possible to read a text file and check it?

Tags: javascript, html

In an HTML form could I type something and see if it matches against something in a text file? If so, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Maybe this would help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/javascript-read-local-text-file

Comment: You should be more specific. The question is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ajax request to load a JSON file from your server

eg if you are using jQuery

```
$.getJSON( "my-json-file.json", function( data ) {
    console.log(data.property);
    console.log(data.anotherProperty);
});
```

this would assume you have a JSON file in your server root folder called `my-json-file.json` with this structure

```
{
    "property": "the data you want to store"
    "anotherProperty": 999999
}
```

Be aware that you would have to wait for this JSON file to be loaded first before you could access and use the data in it. Eg the function with the 2 console logs in it will only be called once the JSON file is loaded

Answer (score 0):

In HTML and Javascript fortunately you can't interact with files in your file system.
I suggest you to use [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) to download the information and compare the result with the inputs.

Comment: You can if the selection of the file is user generated.